# SQL query execution order error

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio

Starting to learn sql and having trouble with my query. I have - 2 tables calendar and activities and FK table DateActivities. Got 2 simple lists calendar with dates and activities. I want to be able with a button click to enter new activity through text box on selected date. But when I do that I get error on a query. Thanks for your help.

```
private void btnAddToDate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string query = "DECLARE @ActivitiesId TABLE (Id INT) " + 
                       "INSERT INTO Activities (Name) " +
                       "OUTPUT INSERTED.ID INTO @ActivitiesId Id(Id) " +
                       "VALUES (@ActivitiesName) " +
                       "INSERT INTO DateActivities VALUES (@CalendarId, @ActivitiesId)";

        using (connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
        {
            connection.Open();
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ActivitiesName", textDate.Text);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CalendarId", listCalendar.SelectedValue);
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

        FillCalendar();
        FillActivities();
    }
```

Comment: Put try-catch block on your code, then paste the exception here... We cannot read your mind.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to execute multiple statement and thus need to separate them with `;` as line terminator like below else it's treated as single statement to execute. If you just copy/paste the statement block in SSMS you will get the same error.

```
"DECLARE @ActivitiesId TABLE (Id INT); " + 
                       "INSERT INTO Activities (Name) " +
                       "OUTPUT INSERTED.ID INTO @ActivitiesId Id(Id) " +
                       "VALUES (@ActivitiesName); " +
                       "INSERT INTO DateActivities VALUES (@CalendarId, @ActivitiesId)"
```

You should better pull this off to a stored procedure instead running as adhoc query.

Answer (score 0):

You are inserting whole table in the column value of `DateActivities` which is obviously wrong and will fail, you need to use another variable to hold the `ActivityId` and then insert it next, see below:

```
"DECLARE @ActivitiesId TABLE (Id INT)
 DECLARE @ActivityId INT " + 
                       "INSERT INTO Activities (Name) " +
                       "OUTPUT INSERTED.ID INTO @ActivitiesId Id(Id) " +
                       "VALUES (@ActivitiesName) " +
                       "SELECT @ActivityId = Id from @ActivitiesId"
                       "INSERT INTO DateActivities VALUES (@CalendarId, @ActivityId)";
```